# Mail with templates from DB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Laravel mail method is by default searching templates in views/emails folder. I would to use mail method with templates stored in DB. How should I modify mail so it could grab templates form any source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel mail method does not search for templates in views/emails folder, You have to mention the blade template name which you want to use for the mail.

Let us say you have a folder called **mymailtemplates** inside **views** folder and a template called **welcome.blade.php** inside it, then you can use this template to send mail as below

```
Mail::send('mymailtemplates.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');

    $message->attach($pathToFile);
});
```

Now if you want to use templates which are stored in DB, get those in a variables and create a dummy blade file (dummy.blade.php) which does nothing but echo the content given to it(in this case the template from the DB), you can now send mail using the template stored in DB like so,

```
Mail::send('mymailtemplates.welcome', $templatedata, function($message)
{
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');

    $message->attach($pathToFile);
});
```

where $templatedata would contain the template code phased from DB.

Comment: Can you please share the code on how to do this: "get those in a variables and create a dummy blade file (dummy.blade.php) which does nothing but echo the content given to it"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for the sake of completeness:

First you need to create a template named example.blade.php created in resources/views/email: 'email.example'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-EN">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#11C9FF">
        {!! $body !!}
    </body>
</html>
```

Ofcourse you can use template inheritance here but let's keep it simple.

With the template created next get the record containing the content for this email. I assume you have a HTML mail template stored in a model named (for example) 'Emails' (with columns: id, subject, body).

**In your controller function load the template content:**

```
// assuming your email template has an id of 1!    
$mailtemplate = Emails::find(1);
```

Now the variable $mailtemplate contains:

```
[
    'id'    => '1'
    'title' => 'The subject of the email',
    'body'  => '<p>The content of the email</p> '
]
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
Mail::send('email.example', $mailtemplate, function($message) use $mailtemplate
{
    $message->subject($mailtemplate['title']);        
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');
    $message->to('foo@example.com');
});
```

In your template you will have the variables available by their element name (id, subject, body).